# Can i see who created a notification in tfs 2015?

Tags: search, notifications, creation, tfs-2015

I am using tfs 2015 and want to find the creator of a specific notification. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the email notification you can find the creator's name. The notification's bottom looks like below:

> Notes:
>   - All dates and times are shown in UTC+01:00:00 Romance Standard Time
>   - You are receiving this notification because of a subscription created by John, Doe with Id 304 Provided by Microsoft Visual Studio®
>   Team Foundation Server